# Python Code Runs in Spyder but not Anaconda Prompt -- ModueNotFoundError

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am in need of some help with the below.  Using Python 3 code on Windows 10.  Written in Spyder over Anaconda install and custom environment.

I have some code that runs in Spyder but not Anaconda Prompt.  It gets a ModuleNotFoundError.  The directory/file structure is like this:

my_python

- smb_bau

  - etl

    - **init**.py
    - etl_globals.py
  - **init**.py
  - my_config.conf
  - my_connections.py
  - my_definitions.py
- **init**.py

(underscores round init not displaying for some reason)

Some notes before the problematic code:
It's just test code for now that will be replaced with the real hive code later.
The code works when all the files are in one foler.
Th my_ prefixes are just to avoid any word that might cause issues while testing.

In my_connections I have this code:

```
class hive_connection:
        def __init__(self):
            self.my_name = None
            self.my_town = None

            import configparser
            from smb_bau.my_definitions import CONFIG_PATH

            config = configparser.ConfigParser()        
            config.read(CONFIG_PATH)
            my_details = config["my_details"]
    
            self.my_name = my_details["my_name"]
            self.my_town = my_details["my_town"]
```

And this is what's in my_definitions:

```
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'my_config.conf')
```

(I gratefully stole this from another thread to solve the issue of getting config info from a different folder).

The file I run is  etl_globals which contains this code:

```
from smb_bau.my_connections import hive_connection

hive = hive_connection()

print(hive.my_name, hive.my_town)
```

When I run etl_globals in Spyder it works perfectly. But it fails in Anaconda Prompt.

I open up Anaconda Prompt, activate my environment, navigate to the etl folder, and enter python etl_globals.py

The error message I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "etl_globals.py", line 1, in 
from smb_bau.my_connections import hive_connection
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smb_bau'

I don't understand why the import of modules works in Spyder but not Anaconda Prompt.

The overarching goal is to be able to not have all the files in one folder.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks.

Edit:

Just to be sure what the issue is I simplified it to create a file called my_functions (in the smb_bau folder) with this in:

def fn_test():
print(5)

And a file in the etl folder called my_test with this in:

from smb_bau.my_functions import fn_test

fn_test()

And got the same error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "my_test.py", line 1, in 
from smb_bau.my_functions import fn_test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smb_bau'

Why does from smb_bau.my_functions import xxx work in Spyder but not Anaconda prompt?

Also, this may be relevant:  the only reason there is a folder called my_python at the top is that I was getting an error saying no module named smb_bau.  So I moved it all down a level and then it would accept smb_bau as a module but only in Spyder).

I also just checked PYTHONPATH and the root folder is there.

I have only been using Python for a week so I'm sure there are other bit of my code that aren't great -- but it does work in the spyder client.

Thanks and sorry if any of this is unclear.

Comment: Maybe what you are locking for is running your code as a module (i.e with the `-m` flag)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for replying.  I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.  In the end I had to put all the "main" scripts in the top level -- along with connections, definitions and config -- then have separate folders for the modules relating to the "mains".  It's better than having it all in one folder -- but I do still have one folder with all the mains in that are not directly related along with the generic code -- when I'd prefer distinct, contained folders.  Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: So it seems that when running from command prompt, the code will look down using the folder.file / package.module notation, but not up.  The internet is awash with people trying to solve this kind of issue.  A lot of suggestions revolve around changing the sys path but I feel it must be possible to do it without that.  (And I tried that and it didn't work).

Comment: @DanielAlthviz I persevered with your -m suggestion and it worked a treat -- thank you.

Comment: Nice, glad it worked!